# The Borg uses many numbers as species designation, who were Species 1?

Tags: star-trek, borg

The Borg has always referred to other species by numbers (i.e. 8472, 3259 for Vulcans, 5618 for Humans ..etc ). It is assumed according to [this](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_species_designations) that the numbers were incremental based on first encounter with few exceptions. My question is: has there been any reference in Star Trek (canon or non-canon) to the identity of species 1, or who are the first species to be assimilated by the Borg?

Comment: Maybe species 1 was the initial species who created the borg entity. Perhaps it was born from a brain-computer interface which everyone loved + uber virus from hell, that took over the planet, then eventually moved to other planets. Probably the first few where some animals too. Lol, borg tiger!

Comment: Considering their core is "Unimatrix 0" in ST:Voyager then the first species to become Borg would be species 0 - the next distinct species to be assimilated would be 1.

Comment: I don't think that anyone, even the Borg, can answer that question. As of the 15th century, the Borg had only assimilated a few dozen systems. The Borg's memories of this era are extremely fragmented. The problem probably gets worse as one goes further back. If we reach the first system they assimilated, it's almost certain that they don't remember that era. That earlier era is probably when species 1 or 0 was first encountered. So the Borg probably don't remember that species.

Comment: @HorusKol Except that their core sector was Unimatrix 1 (or "Unimatrix zero zero one").  Unimatrix 0 was the underground location which was not authorized by the collective.  Presumably Unimatrix 1 was the first (or maybe not, if renumbering or foresight led to 1 being assigned to a location of primary importance.  e.g., if Mr. Borg Inventor lived on Earth, maybe he would call the planet "Celestial Body Number 4", letting Sol be number 1.  Of course, we don't think Borg originated from Earth, but perhaps something analogous.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While not made explicit, **if** we can assume that the numbers are sequential, then the first species would be either the [Caeliar](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Caeliar), Humans, or [Kindir](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Kindir), according to the (non-canon) novel trilogy [Star Trek: Destiny](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Destiny), Book 3 [Lost Souls](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Souls), where one Caeliar merged with two Humans to form the first Borg, and the Kindir were the first species assimilated after that:

> (4527 BCE) After eight days of hiking, the remaining humans returned to Junk Mountain, where they hoped to find the Caeliar alive and still willing to merge with them. However, once there, they found Mantilis apparently empty, although the Caeliar had simply lost the ability to maintain physical cohesion. Sedín - now reduced to a state of pure hunger - possessed all three of them, with Graylock's final thought that “I won't be...won't become...a...cy-“ -Borg. Once Sedín had control over the humans, she realized the female was most precious, and only required one male, so she had Thayer and Graylock kill and eat Pembleton for sustenance. She then instructed them to sleep. Some time later, a mining crew of Kindir native to the planet Arehaz landed on the island; some searching for scientific discovery, some for glory, and some for money. They located the crashed city of Manilis, and were the first to be assimilated by the newly formed Borg.

Discrepancies with the humans being [Species 5618](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_species_designations) could be explained away by the loss of knowledge of these first few species by whatever also caused them to forget the Vaadwaur (from VOY 6x07, [Dragon's Teeth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Teeth_%28episode%29)).